# how to do element exist check using XMLParser()

Tags: groovy

I'm not very good at groovy and sorry in advance it might be very basic.
I've written all my code using XMlParser() class so just cant go back to other available classes ( e.g XMLSlurper).

```
def data ="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <foo>
           </bar>
           </foo>"""
```

i need to check if element  exists. I have used various ways example

```
def xml= new XmlParser().parseText(data);

if(xml.foo.bar.isEmpty())
def value = xml.foo.bar.text()
```

Also tried

```
if(xml.foo.bar == null)
def value = xml.foo.bar.text()
```

Also tried

```
if(xml.foo.bar.size() == 0)  ==> this works in XMLSlurper
def value = xml.foo.bar.text()
```

but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone help please?
I could not find any good documentation/code example as well for XMLParser() class

Answer (score 1):

after paring the `xml` variable already references root element `foo`

so, your accessor should be

```
if(xml.bar)...
```

the code could look like this

```
def data ="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <foo>
           <bar>123</bar>
           </foo>"""

def xml= new XmlParser().parseText(data);

assert xml.bar
def value = xml.bar.text()
```